# Resolving Union Type on different Resolver

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

Taking this scheme:

```
union Vehicle = Airplane | Car

type Airplane {
     title: String
     wingSpan: Int
}

type Car {
    title: String
    wheels: Int
}

type Person {
    vehicle: [Vehicle!]
}
```

And this query:

```
person {
     vehicles {
         ... on Car {
            title
            wheels 
         }
        ... on Airplane {
            title
            wingSpan 
         }
     }
}
```

And these resolvers:

```
// vehicle-resolver.js
export default {
    Vehicle: {
        __resolveType(obj) {
            if (obj.wheels)  {
                return "Car"
            } else {
                return "Airplane"
            }
        }
    }
}

// person-resolver.js
export default {
    Person: {
        vehicles(obj, args, context) {
            // Am I resolving a car or an airplane now - or even both?
            // I need to ask my CarService with `obj.personId` or my AirplaneService with `obj.personId` also, but I only want to query it if the query is asking for it.
        }
    }
}
```

On my `Person -> vehicles(...)` I am unsure when I should query my different services for getting the cars and airplanes? In the method I am not aware of which type we are resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to know what type your Union resolves to **inside** your resolver for `vehicles` because the `__resolveType` field on `Vehicle` actually depends on the data it receives from that resolver.

It sounds like you want the client to be able to request the server to query the Person's cars, or his/her planes, or both, and then have the server act accordingly. This is *typically* done by passing an argument to the field, for example:

```
# type definitions
type Person {
  vehicles(type: VehicleType): [Vehicle!]
}

enum VehicleType {
  CAR
  AIRPLANE
}

//resolver
vehicles(obj, { type }, context) {
  if (type === 'CAR') // fetch and return cars
  if (type === 'AIRPLANE') // fetch and return planes
  // otherwise fetch and return both
}
```

From the client's perspective, it may be a little redundant to have to identify the type as an argument (`type: Car`) and then again within the conditional fragment (`... on Car`), but it's the simplest solution.

**Alternatively,** you could go the less documented path and see what fields were actually requested by the client on a per-request basis. This can be done by digging into the [**fourth** argument passed to the resolver function](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Resolver-function-signature) (info). I think with Apollo, you should be able to fetch the a list of the fields like this:

```
info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.map(s => s.typeCondition.name.value)
```

You could then check which type was requested and have your resolver act accordingly.

**However**, there is an added benefit to doing it the former way (that is by adding a type argument to the field). As a client, if I want to change my query from fetching cars to fetching airplanes, I don't want to have to store two (or more) different queries and have to switch between them depending on the type I'm trying to get.

Within the context of the client, if the type is changeable, it's probably just going to be a variable persisted within the application's state. As a client, then, I'd much rather just pass that variable along with my query. If my variable changes, my query results change, but I don't have to worry about altering the query itself (i.e. it can include the conditional fragments for both types).

Comment: Excellent answer! I am going with the first approach for this time, but very nicely explained!